# Download large SharePoint file using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

We are using CSOM to download a SharePoint Online file using OpenBinaryStream() function. This works fine for files upto 1GB or so but we need to download file of size 25GB. This throws "System out of memory exception" for larger files.

We referred an article at https://piyushksingh.com/2016/08/15/download-large-files-from-sharepoint-online/ which uses Remote Procedure Call to download large files. But it uses auth cookie and needs user credentials. Can RP call be used using Application context? Since we are not storing user credentials and file will be downloaded in the timer job.

Also is there any other way to download files larger than 10GB using CSOM?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look into using modern APIs with PnP Core in place of CSOM.

Here is a link that specifically discusses how to upload and download large files using PnP Core:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/files-large.html

Here is a link to the PnP Core GitHub repository:
https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore

Open **/src/sdk/PnP.Core.sln** to review code and **\src\sdk\PnP.Core.Test\SharePoint\FilesTests.cs** for C# examples.